# android fragment activity menu

Tags: android, android-activity, menu, fragment

I have a class that extends FragmentActivity. No I want to show my menu items at the top of the screen like in actionbar.  How can I do this ?

I have created the menu items  and they are visible hen the hardware button for menu is pressesd but I want to sho them at the top of the screen.

Comment: can u please add at least an image of what you want to do

Comment: You can always use [`AppCompatActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) instead of `FragmentActivity`, unless for some reason you're limited to just the v4 support libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this happens in devices with physical menu button. In devices without that button, all options are displayed in the action bar.

You can force a menu item to be displayed in the action bar by addind "showAlways" to the item that you want.

```
showAsAction=“always”
```

An small example

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:showAsAction="always" />


    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

You must need to ensure that you have enough space for the menu items.

To ensure that I'll have enough space, I use to create a menu with only one item. Then, inside this item, I create another menu. This way, only one button is displayed and all items appear in a floating pop up menu. The main idea is below:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/overflow_item"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_overflow_icon"
          android:title="@string/options"
          android:showAsAction="always" />

      <menu>  
            <item android:id="@+id/action_clear"
                  android:title="@string/clear"
                  android:showAsAction="always" />
    </menu>
</menu>
```